# Using two GPUs for rendering a single animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, hardware

As far as I understand from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79605/using-two-gpus-as-1) (and its answers), if we have two GPUs then Blender can use them simultaneously for a single rendering job (so this would be two times faster).

I did configure Blender to use two GPU: [image: two GPUs] but when I render the animation (Ctrl+F12), only one works: [image: only one GPU]

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I have no 2 GPUs so I cannot test it, but if you read the linked answer, it says Blender renders as many _tiles_ as there are GPUs. I see your tile size is at the default 2048, don't see your output settings, but at 1920×1080 this is just a single tile for one image. In the past, smaller tiles increased render speed (especially for CPU renders) and helped avoiding GPUs running out of memory. Nowadays GPUs can render larger tiles up to complete images sometimes. Try reducing the tile size to 1024 or 512 and see if both GPUs work then.